# Why does the ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined' error occur?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-query

```
export default function VideoDetail() {
  const { etag } = useParams();
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: test,
  } = useQuery(["test"], async () => {
    return fetch("../../data/popular.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });
  const clickedVideo = test.items.find((v) => v.etag === etag);

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  return console.log(clickedVideo);
}
```

The first 5 or so attempts have confirmed that the console outputs a value. However, the error continues to occur after that. There is no modification, but an error occurs What's the reason?

This error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')`

`React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')`

[image]

I don't understand the current error because other components are using `popular.json` without any problems

Comment: The error occurs because `test.items` becomes `undefined`. You will need to debug your code to determine why. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is trying to read the fetched `data`, e.g. `test` prior to it being available. In other words, you can't read `test.items` when `test` is undefined.

Access into the `test` object *after* the loading and error checks checks. It is advisable to also apply null-checks (*i.e. [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)*) on potentially undefined property accesses. Remember also that `Array.prototype.find` also returns `undefined` if no matching element is found via the predicate function, so the code should also conditionally handle this case.

```
export default function VideoDetail() {
  const { etag } = useParams();
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data,
  } = useQuery(["test"], async () => {
    return fetch("../../data/popular.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  const clickedVideo = data?.items?.find((v) => v.etag === etag);

  if (!clickedVideo) {
    return /* no clicked video UI */;

  return /* clicked video UI */;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for always answering me:)
I think it's working well right now Could you check my site?
[link](https://whimsical-lokum-0c6b46.netlify.app/)
It's late today, so I'll check your advice in detail tomorrow and try it
Have a good day!

Comment: @white Welcome, glad to help. Have you updated the code and deployed the changes? What is the link to your app? What steps would one take to verify the changes?

Comment: https://whimsical-lokum-0c6b46.netlify.app/
Only optional chaining is used
As in the previous answer, it is preferred to conditionally write two things when they don't always exist and when they do, right? I think it's a must

Comment: @white Checked the site, looks like you got the data you needed to render the image.

Comment: Thanks to you, the problems of my project are being solved one by one
But,There's one problem
When I click on the videos associated with the videos on the search page, I need to make `detail component` apply to all videos, but I'm trying to write a way to load all the json files I have, but I don't know how to approach them

Comment: I was going to`import` and use the `json` file
But there was an error
Say `/src`cannot be used outside and go to the relevant folder or suggest `symlink`
I read the `npm symlink` document, but I have no idea

Comment: I only use `popular.json` in `detail component`

Comment: Is it a good way to write a new question?

Comment: @white Yes, a new post is preferable since this is a new issue/question.